# no matching member function for call to 'erase'

Tags: c++, templates, factory

Here's the code that causes the error:

Factory.h:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>

namespace BaseSubsystems
{
    template <class T>
    class CFactory
    {
    protected:
        typedef T (*FunctionPointer)();
        typedef std::pair<std::string,FunctionPointer> TStringFunctionPointerPair;
        typedef std::map<std::string,FunctionPointer> TFunctionPointerMap;
        TFunctionPointerMap _table;
    public:
        CFactory () {}
        virtual ~CFactory();
    }; // class CFactory

    template <class T> 
    inline CFactory<T>::~CFactory()
    {
        TFunctionPointerMap::const_iterator it = _table.begin();
        TFunctionPointerMap::const_iterator it2;

        while( it != _table.end() )
        {
            it2 = it;
            it++;
            _table.erase(it2);
        }

    } // ~CFactory
}
```

And the error I get:

```
error: no matching member function for call to 'erase' [3]
                         _table.erase(it2);
                         ~~~~~~~^~~~~
```

Any tips?
Thanks.

Comment: What is the need of `it2` ? How about `_table.erase(it++)` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the signature of [`map::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase) in C++98:

```
void erase( iterator position );
```

This function takes an `iterator` but you're passing a `const_iterator`. That's why the code won't compile.

> How do I fix this?

In C++11 this isn't even a problem, so it doesn't need fixing. That's because in C++11 the `map::erase` function has the following signature, and thus accepts a `const_iterator`.

```
iterator erase( const_iterator position );
```

If you can't use the new standard, you'll have to change your variables to `iterator` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You are passing a const_iterator to a method which expects a plain iterator.

See: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/erase/

Answer (score 2):

See what the master says:

**Scot Meyers in Effective STL**

Item 26. Prefer iterator to const iterator, reverse_iterator, and const_reverse_iterator. Though containers support four iterator types, one of those types has privileges the others do not have. That type is iterator, iterator is special.

```
typedef deque<int> IntDeque; //STL container and
typedef lntDeque::iterator Iter; // iterator types are easier
typedef lntDeque::const_iterator ConstIter; // to work with if you
// use some typedefs
Iter i;
ConstIter ci;
… //make i and ci point into
// the same container
if (i == ci ) ... //compare an iterator
// and a const_iterator
```

**Item 27. Use distance and advance to convert a container's const_iterators to iterators.**

```
typedef deque<int> IntDeque; //convenience typedefs
typedef lntDeque::iterator Iter;
typedef lntDeque::const_iterator ConstIter;
ConstIter ci; // ci is a const_iterator
…
Iter i(ci); // error! no implicit conversion from
// const_iterator to iterator
Iter i(const_cast<Iter>(ci)); // still an error! can't cast a
// const_iterator to an iterator
```

**What works is advance and distance**

```
typedef deque<int> IntDeque; //as before
typedef IntDeque::iterator Iter;
typedef IntDeque::const_iterator ConstIter;
IntDeque d;
ConstIter ci;
… // make ci point into d
Iter i(d.begin()); // initialize i to d.begin()
Advance(i, distance(i, ci)) //move i up to where ci is
// (but see below for why this must
// be tweaked before it will compile)
```